# Servidor web NodeJS con Express. Sequelize ORM lanza error de asociaciones inesperado

Tags: javascript, nodejs, express, sequelize

Soy un miembro de un grupo de 3 personas para un proyecto de instituto y estamos haciendo una aplicación que se comunica con un servidor para servir ficheros estáticos, juegos js. He creado una API REST en la misma aplicación para obtener y enviar datos.
Estamos utilizando esto módulos: Express, Sequelize y Nunjucks. Y utilizo Sequelize Auto para generar los modelos.
Estoy teniendo problemas con la API.

Para empezar generé los modelos con el comando `sequelize-automate -t js -h localhost -d clvgamehub.test -u puser -p <password> -P 5432 -e postgres -o models`. Los tuve que cambiar manualmente, tanto el nombre y el contenido (funciona correctamente).
Estos son los modelos.

```js
// Ahievement.js
const Sequelize = require('sequelize');

const attributes = {
    id: {
        autoIncrement: true,
        type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
        allowNull: false,
        primaryKey: true
    },
    name: {
        type: DataTypes.STRING(20),
        allowNull: false
    },
    description: {
        type: DataTypes.STRING(90),
        allowNull: false
    },
    game_id: {
        type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
        allowNull: false,
        references: {
            model: 'Game',
            key: 'id'
        }
    }
};

const options = {
    sequelize,
    tableName: 'achievement',
    schema: 'public',
    timestamps: false,
    indexes: [
    {
        name: "achievement_pkey",
        unique: true,
        fields: [
                 { name: "id" },
                 ]
    },
    ]
};

const Achievement = sequelize.define('Achievement', attributes, options);

module.exports = Achievement;
```

```js
// Game.js
const { DataTypes } = require('sequelize');
module.exports = function(sequelize) {
    const attributes = {
        id: {
            autoIncrement: true,
            type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
            allowNull: false,
            primaryKey: true
        },
        name: {
            type: DataTypes.STRING(50),
            allowNull: false
        },
        directory: {
            type: DataTypes.STRING(50),
            allowNull: false
        }
    };

    const options = {
        sequelize,
        tableName: 'game',
        schema: 'public',
        timestamps: false,
        indexes: [
        {
            name: "game_pkey",
            unique: true,
            fields: [
                     { name: "id" },
                     ]
        },
        ]
    };
    return sequelize.define('Game', attributes, options);
};
```

```js
// Scoreboard.js
const { DataTypes } = require('sequelize');
module.exports = function(sequelize) {

    const attributes = {
        id: {
            autoIncrement: true,
            type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
            allowNull: false,
            primaryKey: true
        },
        user_id: {
            type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
            allowNull: false,
            references: {
                model: 'User',
                key: 'id'
            }
        },
        game_id: {
            type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
            allowNull: false,
            references: {
                model: 'Game',
                key: 'id'
            }
        },
        score: {
            type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
            allowNull: false
        }
    };

    const options = {
        sequelize,
        tableName: 'scoreboard',
        schema: 'public',
        timestamps: false,
        indexes: [
        {
            name: "scoreboard_pkey",
            unique: true,
            fields: [
                     { name: "id" },
                     ]
        },
        ]
    };

    return sequelize.define('Scoreboard', attributes, options);
};
```

```js
// User.js
const { DataTypes } = require('sequelize');
module.exports = function(sequelize) {

    const attributes = {
        id: {
            autoIncrement: true,
            type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
            allowNull: false,
            primaryKey: true
        },
        nickname: {
            type: DataTypes.STRING(20),
            allowNull: false,
            unique: "user_nickname_key"
        },
        password: {
            type: DataTypes.STRING(32),
            allowNull: false
        }
    };

    const options = {
        sequelize,
        tableName: 'user',
        schema: 'public',
        timestamps: false,
        indexes: [
        {
            name: "user_nickname_key",
            unique: true,
            fields: [
                     { name: "nickname" },
                     ]
        },
        {
            name: "user_pkey",
            unique: true,
            fields: [
                     { name: "id" },
                     ]
        },
        ]
    };

    return sequelize.define('User', attributes, options);
};
```

```js
// UserAchievements.js
const { DataTypes } = require('sequelize');
module.exports = function(sequelize) {

    const attributes = {
        id: {
            autoIncrement: true,
            type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
            allowNull: false,
            primaryKey: true
        },
        user_id: {
            type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
            allowNull: false,
            references: {
                model: 'User',
                key: 'id'
            }
        },
        achievement_id: {
            type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
            allowNull: false,
            references: {
                model: 'Achievement',
                key: 'id'
            }
        }
    };

    const options = {
        sequelize,
        tableName: 'user_achievements',
        schema: 'public',
        timestamps: false,
        indexes: [
        {
            name: "user_achievements_pkey",
            unique: true,
            fields: [
                     { name: "id" },
                     ]
        },
        ]
    };
    
    return sequelize.define('UserAchievements', attributes, options);
};
```

Este es el fichero que instancia la conexión a la base de datos.

```js
// db.js
const settings = require('./settings');
const { Sequelize } = require('sequelize');

module.exports = new Sequelize(settings.database.name, settings.database.user, settings.database.pass, {
    host: settings.database.host,
    dialect: settings.database.dialect,
    port: settings.database.port,
    logging: false,
});
```

El fichero principal.

```js
// main.js
/* import sequelize config */
const db = require('./db');

/* import sequelize models */ 
const initModels = require('./models/init-models');

/* instantiate Sequelize connector */
db.authenticate()
.then(() => {
    console.log('Connection to database successful.');
    /* initialize Sequelize models and perform relationships */
    initModels(db);
    console.log('Models instantiated.')
    

    const settings = require('./settings');
    const express = require('express');
    const cors = require('cors');
    var nunjucks = require('nunjucks');
    const bodyparser = require('body-parser');
    const server = express();

    /* import middleware */
    const RequestLogger = require('./middleware/RequestLogger');
    const ErrorLogger = require('./middleware/ErrorLogger');

    /* handlers import */
    const IndexHandler = require('./handlers/IndexHandler');
    const ApiHandler = require('./handlers/ApiHandler');




    /* template engine renderer */
    nunjucks.configure(settings.server.templates_dir, {
        autoescape: true,
        cache: false,
        express: server,
    });


    /* middleware use */
    server.use(cors());
    server.use(bodyparser.json());
    server.use(express.json());
    server.use(bodyparser.urlencoded({
        extended: true
    }));
    server.use('/static', express.static(settings.server.static_dir));

    /* request logger */
    server.use(RequestLogger);

    /* server contexts */
    server.use('/', IndexHandler);
    server.use('/api', ApiHandler);

    /* error logger */
    server.use(ErrorLogger);

    /* start the server */
    server.listen(settings.server.port, settings.server.host, () => {
        console.log("Started server on %s:%d.", settings.server.host, settings.server.port)
    });

})
.catch((e) => {
    console.log('Connection to database failed.');
    console.error(e)
});
```

El archivo de configuración global.

```js
// settings.js
var settings = {
    server: {
        host: '127.0.0.1',
        port: 8080,
        base_dir: '/home/samba/share/proyecto/development/clvgamehub/',
        templates_dir: '/home/samba/share/proyecto/development/clvgamehub/templates/',
        static_dir: '/home/samba/share/proyecto/development/clvgamehub/static/',
        games_dir: '/home/samba/share/proyecto/development/clvgamehub/static/games/',
    },
    database: {
        dialect: 'postgres',
        host: '127.0.0.1',
        name: 'clvgamehub.test',
        user: 'puser',
        pass: 'secret',
        port: 5432,
    },
};

switch(process.env.NODE_ENV){
    case 'dev':
    {
        settings.server.port = 8080;
        settings.server.host = '127.0.0.1';
    }
    break;
    case 'prod':
    {
        settings.server.port = 80;
        settings.server.host = '0.0.0.0';
    }
    break;
}

module.exports = settings;
```

Y aquí está uno de los controladores, que me falla...

```js
const { Op } = require('sequelize');
const db = require('../db');

const UserAchievements = require('../models/UserAchievements')(db);
const Achievement = require('../models/Achievement')(db);
const Game = require('../models/Game')(db);

/**
 * 
 * @param achievement_id
 * @param user_id
 * @return Achievement
 * 
 **/
const getByAchievementAndUser = async(achievement_id, user_id) => {
    try {
        const achievement = await UserAchievements.findOne({
            where: {
                achievement_id: achievement_id,
                user_id: user_id,
            },
        });
        return (achievement) ? achievement : null;
    } catch (e) {
        throw e;
    }
};

/**
 * 
 * @param user_id
 * @return Achievement[]
 * 
 **/
const getByUser = async (user_id) => {
    try {
        const achievement = await UserAchievements.findAll({
            where: {
                user_id: user_id,
            },
        });
        return (achievement.length > 0)? achievement : null;
    } catch (e) {
        throw e;
    }
};

/**
 * 
 * @param game_id
 * @param user_id
 * @return Achievement[]
 * 
 **/
const getAtGameByUser = async (game_id, user_id) => {
    try {
        const achievement = await UserAchievements.findAll({
            where: {
                user_id: user_id,
            },
            include: [
            {
                model: Achievement,
                where: {
                    id: { [Op.col]: 'UserAchievements.achievement_id' },
                },
                include: [
                {
                    model: Game,
                    where: {
                        id: game_id
                    }
                }
                ]
            }
            ]
        });
        return (achievement.length > 0) ? achievement : null;
    } catch (e) {
        throw e;
    }
};

/**
 * 
 * @param achievement_id
 * @param user_id
 * @return Achievement
 * 
 **/
const unlockAchievement = async(achievement_id, user_id) => {
    try {
        const achievement = await UserAchievements.create({
            achievement_id: achievement_id,
            user_id: user_id,
        });
        return (achievement) ? achievement : null;
    } catch (e) {
        throw e;
    }
};

module.exports = {
    getByAchievementAndUser,
    getByUser,
    getAtGameByUser,
    unlockAchievement,
};
```

El error se produce en la función `getAtGameByUser` , porque supuestamente, el modelo Achievement y UserAchievements no están asociados. Es la única función de todos los controladores que no me funciona.

Error:
`EagerLoadingError [SequelizeEagerLoadingError]: Achievement is not associated to UserAchievements! at UserAchievements._getIncludedAssociation (/home/samba/share/proyecto/development/clvgamehub/node_modules/sequelize/lib/model.js:565:13) at UserAchievements._validateIncludedElement (/home/samba/share/proyecto/development/clvgamehub/node_modules/sequelize/lib/model.js:502:53) at /home/samba/share/proyecto/development/clvgamehub/node_modules/sequelize/lib/model.js:421:37 at Array.map (<anonymous>) at UserAchievements._validateIncludedElements (/home/samba/share/proyecto/development/clvgamehub/node_modules/sequelize/lib/model.js:417:39) at UserAchievements.findAll (/home/samba/share/proyecto/development/clvgamehub/node_modules/sequelize/lib/model.js:1124:12) at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5) at async Object.getAtGameByUser (/home/samba/share/proyecto/development/clvgamehub/controllers/UserAchievementsController.js:59:23)`
Con ayuda de la documentación de las dos conocidas IAs, escribí las asociaciones en el fichero `init-models.js`, pero no sirven. Las tablas en la base de datos están bien relacionadas, pero aquí dejo el fichero de migración:

```sql
DROP TABLE "user" CASCADE;
DROP TABLE "game" CASCADE;
DROP TABLE "achievement" CASCADE;
DROP TABLE "scoreboard" CASCADE;
DROP TABLE "user_achievements" CASCADE;

CREATE TABLE "user"(
    "id" serial,
    "nickname" varchar(20) unique not null,
    "password" varchar(32) not null,
    primary key ("id")
);

CREATE TABLE "game"(
    "id" serial,
    "name" varchar(50) not null,
    "directory" varchar(50) not null,
    primary key ("id")
);

CREATE TABLE "achievement"(
    "id" serial,
    "name" varchar(20) not null,
    "description" varchar(90) not null,
    "game_id" int not null,
    primary key ("id"),
    constraint "game_fk1" foreign key ("game_id")
        references "game"("id") on update cascade on delete cascade
);

CREATE TABLE "scoreboard"(
    "id" serial,
    "user_id" int not null, 
    "game_id" int not null,
    "score" int not null,
    primary key ("id"),
    constraint "user_fk1" foreign key ("user_id")
        references "user"("id") on update cascade on delete cascade,
    constraint "game_fk2" foreign key ("game_id")
        references "game"("id") on update cascade on delete cascade
);

CREATE TABLE "user_achievements"(
    "id" serial,
    "user_id" int not null,
    "achievement_id" int not null,
    primary key ("id"),
    constraint "user_fk2" foreign key ("user_id")
        references "user"("id") on update cascade on delete cascade,
    constraint "achievement_fk1" foreign key ("achievement_id")
        references "achievement"("id") on update cascade on delete cascade
);
```

```
const db = require('../db');
const DataTypes = require("sequelize").DataTypes;

const _Achievement = require("./Achievement");
const _Game = require("./Game");
const _Scoreboard = require("./Scoreboard");
const _User = require("./User");
const _UserAchievements = require("./UserAchievements");

function initModels(db) {
    const Achievement = _Achievement(db, DataTypes);
    const Game = _Game(db, DataTypes);
    const Scoreboard = _Scoreboard(db, DataTypes);
    const User = _User(db, DataTypes);
    const UserAchievements = _UserAchievements(db, DataTypes);

    UserAchievements.associate = (models) => {
        UserAchievements.belongsTo(models.Achievement, { foreignKey: "achievement_id" });
        UserAchievements.belongsTo(models.User, { foreignKey: "user_id" });
      };

      Achievement.associate = (models) => {
        Achievement.belongsTo(models.Game, { foreignKey: "game_id" });
        Game.hasMany(Achievement, { foreignKey: "game_id" });
        Achievement.hasMany(models.UserAchievements, { foreignKey: "achievement_id" });
      };

      Game.associate = (models) => {
        Game.hasMany(models.Achievement, { foreignKey: "game_id" });
        Game.belongsTo(models.Scoreboard, { foreignKey: "game_id" });
        Scoreboard.hasMany(Game, { foreignKey: "game_id" });
      };

      Scoreboard.associate = (models) => {
        Scoreboard.belongsTo(models.User, { foreignKey: "user_id" });
        User.hasMany(Scoreboard, { foreignKey: "user_id" });
      };

}

module.exports = initModels;
module.exports.initModels = initModels;
module.exports.default = initModels;
```

No logro entender qué estoy haciendo mal, y he buscado información por todos lados. Por favor, necesito ayuda. Cualquier ayuda me sirve, gracias!